# I have used parameters but I'm struggling to login with multi user

Tags: c#, parameters

I have been making a simple web site as Assignment requirements.
I am struggling to make it a multi user login. I tried but nothing is working for me not even errors come up. Can anyone help me out? I tried so many times, I am new to programming and `c#` as well.

```
string Cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string query = "Select Username from Users where username = @username and password = @password;";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Cs))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Username.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Password.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = "UserType";
    con.Open();
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result != null)
    {
    // the error is here when i debugged.i couldn't solve.

        String UserType;
        UserType = result.ToString();
        if (UserType=="Admin") { 
        Response.Redirect("~/Cuhome.aspx");
        }
        else if (UserType=="Member")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/RegisterMem.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LblError.Text = "Invalid Username & Password";
    }
}
```

[image: the table of My database]

Comment: I appreciate this is for an assignment so they're probably not expecting much, but be aware that, in the real world, you shouldn't be storing passwords as plain text. Some of your naming seems a little odd here as well - you have a query that returns a `UserName` (and does nothing with the `@UserType` parameter), but then when you retrieve that value you're calling it `UserType`

Comment: I tried to add the UserType but it gave errors. it is an assignment but i don't know how to make fully functional multi user login.

Comment: Try to [edit] your question and make it clear a) what you're trying to do, b) why you think this code should do it, c) any errors you *are* getting and d) what the code seems to *actually* be doing. We can't run your code, so we need to know all of these things. Ideally, you create a [mcve] (note, it seems daunting to be asked to produce one - but realise that the work of creating one is a *valuable debugging technique*, in and of itself, that it's worth learning to do it)

Comment: Youre selecting username in the Sql but the variable is called UserType. If you're expecting a user type then it explains why it doesn't work: your if statements lack an else block so if the UserName (UserType variable) doesn't match Admin or Member then nothing happens. My guess is that username is returning something like "JoeShmoe" which matches neither Admin nor Member so nothing happens. Add an else block and have it do *something*... Then you should at least see some sort of action take place. Bottom line, it looks like you're selecting the wrong value in your query

Comment: I am checking the username in the If Statement if The username is Admin Or Member. if the results and is matched and not null, then check if the Username has a UserType which is Admin Or Member and assign to their pages accordingly.

Comment: So you're storing "Admin" or "Member" in the actual field called UserName? Edit your post and show an example of the table with a line of data. I think you're thinking by knowing the username, you know what type of user they area and this is not the case.

Comment: I have added my Database Table below the code please. I desperately need help.

Comment: Yes, so as *several* people have repeatedly told you, you're selecting *username* from that table and putting that in your `UserType` variable. Which means it will only every be equal to `ssa`, `daisy` or `Samiya` and will never be equal to either `Admin` or `Member`.

Comment: How do i change that please.any help

Comment: Select UserType instead of UserName in your query and get rid of the parameter for UserType as it's not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change your code to use `cmd.ExecuteReader();`, or change your query to perform a `select count(username) ...`

Currently you are trying to execute a query that returns data as a scalar.